# Sending a webcam input to zoom using a recorded clip

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, video-streaming, webcam, virtual-webcam

I have an idea that I have been working on, but there are some technical details that I would love to understand before I proceed.

From what I understand, Linux communicates with the underlying hardware through the /dev/. I was messing around with my video cam input to zoom and I found someone explaining that I need to create a virtual device and mount it to the output of another program called v4loop.
My questions are

1- How does Zoom detect the webcams available for input. My /dev directory has 2 "files" called video (/dev/video0 and /dev/video1), yet zoom only detects one webcam. Is the webcam communication done through this video file or not? If yes, why does simply creating one doesn't affect Zoom input choices. If not, how does zoom detect the input and read the webcam feed?

2- can I create a virtual device and write a kernel module for it that feeds the input from a local file. I have written a lot of kernel modules, and I know they have a read, write, release methods. I want to parse the video whenever a read request from zoom is issued. How should the video be encoded? Is it an mp4 or a raw format or something else? How fast should I be sending input (in terms of kilobytes). I think it is a function of my webcam recording specs. If it is 1920x1080, and each pixel is 3 bytes (RGB), and it is recording at 20 fps, I can simply calculate how many bytes are generated per second, but how does Zoom expect the input to be Fed into it. Assuming that it is sending the strean in real time, then it should be reading input every few milliseconds. How do I get access to such information?

Thank you in advance. This is a learning experiment, I am just trying to do something fun that I am motivated to do, while learning more about Linux-hardware communication. I am still a beginner, so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are two types of /dev/video* files. One for the metadata and the other is for the actual stream from the webcam. Creating a virtual device of the same type as the stream in the /dev directory did result in Zoom recognizing it as an independent webcam, even without creating its metadata file. I did finally achieve what I wanted, but I used OBS Studio virtual camera feature that was added after update 26.0.1, and it is working perfectly so far.